# Operand type clash: int is incompatible with uniqueidentifier in sqlsever 2012

Tags: sql-server

when i am trying to execute this storted proc am facing an error int is incompatiable with uniqueidentifier.my userid coloumn is bigint

USE [iFlipOut_Dev]
    GO
    /***** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[SaveRegistration]    Script Date: 4/14/2013 3:29:40 PM *****/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SaveRegistration]  
(
   @p_UserId int,
   @p_FirstName nvarchar(150),
   @p_LastName nvarchar(50),
   @p_Gender nvarchar(10),
   @p_Email nvarchar(150),
   @p_Mobile nvarchar(12),
   @p_Phone nvarchar(12),
   @p_DateOfBirth nvarchar(50),
   @p_Address nvarchar(250),
   @p_ZipCode nvarchar(10),
   @p_City nvarchar(100),
   @p_StateId smallint,
   @p_LoginId int,
   @p_UserStatusId smallint,
   @p_LanguageId smallint,
   @p_ModifiedBy bigint,
   @p_CountryId smallint,
   @p_UserImage nvarchar(20),
   @p_publicRegistrationId nvarchar(50),
   @p_TimeZone_Id smallint

   )
AS 
   BEGIN

      SET  NOCOUNT  ON


      IF 
         CASE 
            WHEN EXISTS 
               (
                  SELECT 
                     UD.UserId, 
                     UD.FirstName, 
                     UD.LastName, 
                     UD.Gender, 
                     UD.email, 
                     UD.Mobile, 
                     UD.phone, 
                     UD.DateOfBirth, 
                     UD.Address, 
                     UD.ZipCode, 
                     UD.City, 
                     UD.StateId, 
                     UD.LoginId, 
                     UD.UserStatusId, 
                     UD.LanguageId, 
                     UD.ModifiedBy, 
                     UD.ModifiedDate, 
                     UD.CountryId, 
                     UD.UserImage, 
                     UD.PublicRegistrationId, 
                     UD.TimeZone_Id,
                     UD.IsActivated
                  FROM dbo.UserDetails as UD
                  WHERE UD.UserId = @p_UserId
               ) THEN 1
            ELSE 0
         END <> 0
         /*
         *  Added UserId Coloumn to be inserted in the table
         */

         UPDATE dbo.UserDetails
            SET 
               FirstName = @p_FirstName, 
               LastName = @p_LastName, 
               Gender = @p_Gender, 
               Email = @p_Email, 
               Mobile = @p_Mobile, 
               Phone = @p_Phone, 
               DateOfBirth = @p_DateOfBirth, 
               Address = @p_Address, 
               ZipCode = @p_ZipCode, 
               City = @p_City, 
               StateId = @p_StateId, 
               LoginId = @p_LoginId, 
               UserStatusId = @p_UserStatusId, 
               LanguageId = @p_LanguageId, 
               ModifiedBy = @p_ModifiedBy, 
               ModifiedDate = isnull(getdate(), getdate()), 
               CountryId = @p_CountryId, 
               UserImage = @p_UserImage, 
               PublicRegistrationId=@p_publicregistrationId,
               TimeZone_Id = @p_TimeZone_Id

         WHERE UserDetails.UserId = @p_UserId
      ELSE 
         BEGIN

            /*
            *  added userid coloumn in the insert statement
            */

            INSERT dbo.UserDetails(
               dbo.UserDetails.FirstName, 
               dbo.UserDetails.LastName, 
               dbo.UserDetails.Gender, 
               dbo.UserDetails.email, 
               dbo.UserDetails.Mobile, 
               dbo.UserDetails.Phone, 
               dbo.UserDetails.DateOfBirth, 
               dbo.UserDetails.Address, 
               dbo.UserDetails.ZipCode, 
               dbo.UserDetails.City, 
               dbo.UserDetails.StateId, 
               dbo.UserDetails.LoginId, 
               dbo.UserDetails.UserStatusId, 
               dbo.UserDetails.LanguageId, 
               dbo.UserDetails.ModifiedBy, 
               dbo.UserDetails.ModifiedDate, 
               dbo.UserDetails.CountryId, 
               dbo.UserDetails.UserImage, 
               dbo.UserDetails.PublicRegistrationId, 
               dbo.UserDetails.TimeZone_Id)


               VALUES (
                  @p_FirstName, 
                  @p_LastName, 
                  @p_Gender, 
                  @p_Email, 
                  @p_Mobile, 
                  @p_Phone, 
                  @p_DateOfBirth, 
                  @p_Address, 
                  @p_ZipCode, 
                  @p_City, 
                  @p_StateId, 
                  @p_LoginId, 
                  @p_UserStatusId, 
                  @p_LanguageId, 
                  @p_ModifiedBy, 
                  isnull(getdate(), getdate()), 
                  @p_CountryId, 
                  @p_UserImage, 
                  newid(), 
                  @p_TimeZone_Id)





            SET @p_UserId = scope_identity()

         END

      SELECT @p_UserId AS UserId

   END
```

Comment: Something that you/the author of the stored prcoedure think is an `int` is in fact a `uniqueidentifier`. Without seeing your calling code and/or your schema, we can't assist further. However, I can point out that your `EXISTS()` code seems to be more complex than it needs to be. (`IF CASE WHEN EXISTS() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END <> 0` could be just `IF EXISTS()`, and there's no need to have a column list in there - it's one of the few places where `SELECT *` is usually more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Int and GUID data-types are not compatible. Can you specify, where exactly error occurs.

I also little rewrote your sp -

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SaveRegistration]  
(
   @p_UserId int,
   @p_FirstName nvarchar(150),
   @p_LastName nvarchar(50),
   @p_Gender nvarchar(10),
   @p_Email nvarchar(150),
   @p_Mobile nvarchar(12),
   @p_Phone nvarchar(12),
   @p_DateOfBirth nvarchar(50),
   @p_Address nvarchar(250),
   @p_ZipCode nvarchar(10),
   @p_City nvarchar(100),
   @p_StateId smallint,
   @p_LoginId int,
   @p_UserStatusId smallint,
   @p_LanguageId smallint,
   @p_ModifiedBy bigint,
   @p_CountryId smallint,
   @p_UserImage nvarchar(20),
   @p_publicRegistrationId nvarchar(50),
   @p_TimeZone_Id smallint

   )
AS BEGIN

      SET  NOCOUNT  ON

      IF EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM dbo.UserDetails UD
            WHERE UD.UserId = @p_UserId
        ) BEGIN


         UPDATE dbo.UserDetails
            SET 
               FirstName = @p_FirstName, 
               LastName = @p_LastName, 
               Gender = @p_Gender, 
               Email = @p_Email, 
               Mobile = @p_Mobile, 
               Phone = @p_Phone, 
               DateOfBirth = @p_DateOfBirth, 
               Address = @p_Address, 
               ZipCode = @p_ZipCode, 
               City = @p_City, 
               StateId = @p_StateId, 
               LoginId = @p_LoginId, 
               UserStatusId = @p_UserStatusId, 
               LanguageId = @p_LanguageId, 
               ModifiedBy = @p_ModifiedBy, 
               ModifiedDate = getdate(), 
               CountryId = @p_CountryId, 
               UserImage = @p_UserImage, 
               PublicRegistrationId=@p_publicregistrationId,
               TimeZone_Id = @p_TimeZone_Id
         WHERE UserDetails.UserId = @p_UserId

      END
      ELSE BEGIN

            INSERT dbo.UserDetails(
               FirstName, 
               LastName, 
               Gender, 
               email, 
               Mobile, 
               Phone, 
               DateOfBirth, 
               Address, 
               ZipCode, 
               City, 
               StateId, 
               LoginId, 
               UserStatusId, 
               LanguageId, 
               ModifiedBy, 
               ModifiedDate, 
               CountryId, 
               UserImage, 
               PublicRegistrationId, 
               TimeZone_Id)
            SELECT
                  @p_FirstName, 
                  @p_LastName, 
                  @p_Gender, 
                  @p_Email, 
                  @p_Mobile, 
                  @p_Phone, 
                  @p_DateOfBirth, 
                  @p_Address, 
                  @p_ZipCode, 
                  @p_City, 
                  @p_StateId, 
                  @p_LoginId, 
                  @p_UserStatusId, 
                  @p_LanguageId, 
                  @p_ModifiedBy, 
                  getdate(), 
                  @p_CountryId, 
                  @p_UserImage, 
                  newid(), 
                  @p_TimeZone_Id

            SELECT @p_UserId = scope_identity()

         END

      SELECT @p_UserId AS UserId

   END
```

Cleanup means that:

```
IF 
         CASE 
            WHEN EXISTS 
               (
                  SELECT 
                     UD.UserId, 
                     UD.FirstName, 
                     UD.LastName, 
                     UD.Gender, 
                     UD.email, 
                     UD.Mobile, 
                     UD.phone, 
                     UD.DateOfBirth, 
                     UD.Address, 
                     UD.ZipCode, 
                     UD.City, 
                     UD.StateId, 
                     UD.LoginId, 
                     UD.UserStatusId, 
                     UD.LanguageId, 
                     UD.ModifiedBy, 
                     UD.ModifiedDate, 
                     UD.CountryId, 
                     UD.UserImage, 
                     UD.PublicRegistrationId, 
                     UD.TimeZone_Id,
                     UD.IsActivated
                  FROM dbo.UserDetails as UD
                  WHERE UD.UserId = @p_UserId
               ) THEN 1
            ELSE 0
         END <> 0
```

Can optimize to:

```
 IF EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM dbo.UserDetails UD
            WHERE UD.UserId = @p_UserId
        ) BEGIN
```

Comment: can you specify, where exactly error occurs? or add schema description for table dbo.UserDetails

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question - all it does is some style cleanup. Probably shouldn't be an answer.

Comment: am getting the error at insert statement and update statement

Comment: I agree with @Damien_The_Unbeliever. I waiting for a reply, where the error to correct it.

Comment: @krish can you look in the profiler, what values ​​you insert when executing this sp?

Comment: what does style cleanup means

Comment: i have used same what you have answered still returning the same error

Comment: The main problem is that you insert guid in int column. Please add schema description for table dbo.UserDetails and specify with what parameters you executed your stored procedure (for this, use profiler).
Update applies to your question “what does style cleanup means”.